# what can i do to fix the code to make the nested loop work in python

Tags: python-3.x

For [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3cWe.png), `list1 = [1,2,3,4]` and the code worked as I expected. However,
when I change `list1 = [1,8,6,4]` the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV9A8.png) changed.

There is something wrong with the nested loop ?

Comment: Post your code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: I second that, please paste your code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace gt1: with i: and it should work. `for j in list1[i:]:`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're confusing the indices and the values of the numbers in your list.

Let me explain your code to you. I've rewritten your code in a simplified way:

Code sample 1:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
x = 0

for i, val in enumerate(list1):
    if val == list1[-1]:
        break

    x+=val
    y = 0

    for j in list1[val:]:
        y+=j

    print('(x, y):', (x,y))
```

Result:

```
(x, y): (1, 9)
(x, y): (3, 7)
(x, y): (6, 4)
```

---

Code sample 2:

```
list1 = [1,8,6,4]
x = 0

for i, val in enumerate(list1):
    if val == list1[-1]:
        break

    x+=val
    y = 0

    for j in list1[val:]:
        y+=j

    print('(x, y):', (x,y))
```

Result:

```
(x, y): (1, 18)
(x, y): (9, 0)
(x, y): (15, 0)
```

---

Notice that in this portion of your *original* code, you are slicing your list using a value from the list rather than the index you intend to use:

```
# from original code
for j in list1[gt1:]:
        y+=j
```

The list `list1 = [1,8,6,4]` makes it such that you are slicing your list with a value that is beyond the greatest index in your list, therefore the resulting sums are zero.

Observe the results when I correct this:

```
# CORRECT CODE
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
x = 0

for i, val in enumerate(list1):
    if val == list1[-1]:
        break

    x+=val
    y = 0

    for j in list1[i:]: #NOTICE THE CORRECTION
        y+=j

    print('(x, y):', (x,y))

print("\n-----------------\n")

list1 = [1,8,6,4]
x = 0

for i, val in enumerate(list1):
    if val == list1[-1]:
        break

    x+=val
    y = 0

    for j in list1[i:]: #NOTICE THE CORRECTION
        y+=j

    print('(x, y):', (x,y))
```

Results:

```
(x, y): (1, 10)
(x, y): (3, 9)
(x, y): (6, 7)

-----------------

(x, y): (1, 19)
(x, y): (9, 18)
(x, y): (15, 10)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help a lot. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am quite a newbie in this code but i will try. By the way, may I contact you through facebook or sth similar?

Comment: i already uploaded my twitter account. Please contact me, i would love to be friends with you. Thanks for your kindness